# What's considered nesting in python?

Tags: python

I have always considered nesting as embedding one object in another object of the same type.

But I was recently told that nesting also means embedding objects of different type so the following has three levels of nesting.

```
def my_function():
    # first level of nesting ???
    while expr:
        # second level of nesting ???
        if expr:
            # third level of nesting ???
            do_something()
        else:
            # third level of nesting ???
            do_something_else()
```

I have searched online but couldn't find any concise answer.

Comment: That's indentation, not nesting.

Comment: First off those are not objects and they are not embedded in anything. Those are statements inside a function.

Comment: Nesting is when your particular code performs some function and is contained within code that performs a broader function.

Comment: so, puting statements inside a function is just that, so no nesting here, the same applies to while or for loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least 2 definitions of nesting:

- Putting one object inside of another could be considered nesting (think Russian Nesting Dolls), but it's more generally referred to as **composition**. I'm guessing this is what you were referring to as putting one object inside of another; although the types have no requirement to be of the same type, and often aren't unless you're defining a recursive data structure.
- What you show in the code snippet could also be considered nesting, since you have expressions/statements inside of other expressions/statements. Given its Python though, it could also be considered the **level of indentation**, since indentation level indicates nesting level in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Nesting means putting a block of code in another block.
The following are the examples of nested blocks.

```
if True:
    a = 0 
    a = a + 5 
    if a < 10: 
        a = 20

for i in [1, 2, 3]: 
    print i
    try:
        b = i + 10
    except:
        print 'bye'
```

In the above code, the block **if a < 10** is nested under the block **if True**, the same way **try** and **except** blocks are nested under the block of **for** loop